# Hospital infection data

Tags: data-request, medical, time-series

I am looking for hospital infection data sets for modelling purposes: time series about infections such as MRSA, VRE, etc. The data set should contain incidence/prevalence time series in a hospital ward and admission/discharge data.

Is there any available data set like this?

Answer (score 2):

Raw counts of hospital acquired infections in england are available on the NHS Digital [Indicator Portal](https://indicators.hscic.gov.uk/webview/).

MRSA and C.Diff stats are found in the sections NHS Outcomes Framework|Domain 5...|Improvement Areas

The data as presented don't include information about the ward or the total number of patients being treated in the hospital, but those statistics are available elsewhere on the NHS Digital site.